# INNER JOIN não retorna todos os registros

Tags: mysql, sql-select, mariadb

Fala pessoal, bom dia.

Possuo duas tabelas em meu banco (cliente e telefone), onde alguns clientes possuem diversos registros e outros nenhum. Inicialmente estava com problemas em "aninhar" todos os registros da tabela telefone na mesma linha, mas já solucionei conforme a dica do @Motta, porém, me surgiu um outros problema: Os registros da tabela cliente que não possuem relacionamento na tabela telefone não são retornados e necessito fazer todos serem exibidos (com ou sem relacionamento). É possível fazer isto na mesma query?

Banco:

Cliente (ID | NOME)
Telefone (ID | FK_CLIENTE | NUMERO)

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.`id`, c.`nome`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.`numero` ORDER BY t.`id` ASC) AS `telefone` FROM `cliente` AS c INNER JOIN `telefone` AS t ON t.`fk_cliente` = c.`id` GROUP BY c.`id`
```

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: @Motta Obrigado pelo feedback, já consegui implementar desta forma. Agora estou com outra questão. Vou editar minha pergunta pra ficar mais clara e específica.

Comment: Troque o `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Trará todos os clientes, mesmo os que não tem telefone associado.

Comment: @anonimo obrigado pelo feedback, resolveu a questão. Sabia que eu estava vacilando sobre algo na instrução.